# How can i run this type of thread in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have 6 threads loaded and it runs concurrently but i would like to put timers in for it to work in the below way:

- Thread group 1 starts at start of test
- After 5 mins thread group 2 starts off in parallel with thread group 1
- After another 5 mins thread group 3 starts off, again in parallel
- After another 5 mins, thread group 4 starts off. This is group uses a file and stops at the end of the file, leaving just thread groups 1, 2 and 3 running.
- A short pause (10 seconds?)
- Then thread group 5 starts off, again driven from a file
- When that finishes, thread group 6 starts off
- When that’s finished, the test finishes: all the threads should stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to handle this with the [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller).

Depending on your expertise in BeanShell or Javascript it might be very easy or a little difficult. You could add a counter to the first thread and after the counter hits a number, it starts the second group.  It would have the loop running as false and then when it becomes true, the next group would start.

You could also look at the Timers section of controllers. Again, using Beanshell or Javascript this can delay starts.

Sorry, but I don't have a more specific example. These should get you started.

Comment: How do i stop it from looping forever after the first while evaluation. @james

Comment: How do i stop it from looping forever after the first while evaluation.